# horizontal form with inline form bootstrap while keeping everything aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do an in-line form for the `123` `456` `789`
and price fields while keeping all first label is always taking col-md-1 space and in-line with other labels.

Here is the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEYYEj

Here is the code

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="padding: 30px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;">


    <form data-toggle="validator" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/seller/new-listings" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="true">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-11">


                <input class="maxlength-handler   form-control input-xlarge" data-error="Min 2 Letters" data-minlength="2" id="name" label="False" maxlength="56" name="name" required="" type="text" value="">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <textarea class="maxlength-handler   form-control input-xlarge" data-error="Min 20 Letters" data-minlength="20" id="description" label="False" maxlength="300" name="description" required="" style="height:100px;"></textarea>

            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">123:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="123-input form-control" id="123" maxlength="4" name="123" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">456:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="cbn-input form-control" id="" maxlength="4" name="" style="   width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">678:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="cbn-input form-control" id="" maxlength="4" name="" style="   width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>







    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1g </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1g </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1/8 </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1/4 </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1/2 </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1 oz </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Stock:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="form-control only-numbers" data-error="Stock required" data-minlength="1" id="stock" maxlength="3" name="stock" placeholder="Total Available Inventory for sale measured by Gram" required="" type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Published:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11"><select class="form-control" id="published" name="published"><option value="published">Published</option><option value="not_published">Unpublished</option></select></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">SKU:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11"><input class="form-control" id="sku" name="sku" type="text" value=""></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is what you were looking for, but if you drop some of the form-groups and change the field divs to `col-md-1` too, then you get the fields you want inlined...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEYYdb

[image: Fields inlined]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">123:</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="123-input form-control" id="123" maxlength="4" name="123" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">456:</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="cbn-input form-control" id="" maxlength="4" name="" style="   width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">678:</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="cbn-input form-control" id="" maxlength="4" name="" style="   width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with that is that the  bootstrap - validator library need each field to have its own form group because it turns the form group red. This way everything turns red when one of them is empty. Its okay ill use this tho.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.inline-inp,.inline-inp .col-md-1,.inline-inp .col-md-11{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="padding: 30px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;">


    <form data-toggle="validator" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/seller/new-listings" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="true">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-11">


                <input class="maxlength-handler   form-control input-xlarge" data-error="Min 2 Letters" data-minlength="2" id="name" label="False" maxlength="56" name="name" required="" type="text" value="">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <textarea class="maxlength-handler   form-control input-xlarge" data-error="Min 20 Letters" data-minlength="20" id="description" label="False" maxlength="300" name="description" required="" style="height:100px;"></textarea>

            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div>

    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">123:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="123-input form-control" id="123" maxlength="4" name="123" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">456:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="cbn-input form-control" id="" maxlength="4" name="" style="   width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">678:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="cbn-input form-control" id="" maxlength="4" name="" style="   width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="0">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div>


    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1g </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1g </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1/8 </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1/4 </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1/2 </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group inline-inp">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <label class="control-label" style="padding-right:5px;">1 oz </label>
            <input class="cbd-input form-control" data-error="Price required" data-minlength="1" id="price" maxlength="8" name="price" required="" style=" width:80px; display:inline-block; " type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>


    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Stock:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input class="form-control only-numbers" data-error="Stock required" data-minlength="1" id="stock" maxlength="3" name="stock" placeholder="Total Available Inventory for sale measured by Gram" required="" type="text" value="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Published:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11"><select class="form-control" id="published" name="published"><option value="published">Published</option><option value="not_published">Unpublished</option></select></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">SKU:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11"><input class="form-control" id="sku" name="sku" type="text" value=""></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Problem with this is that labels are on top and not in lined not in lined.